# openvpn no access - No route to host

Tags: networking, openvpn, openwrt

I am using a router (openwrt) as server.

route -n (before VPN):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.2     127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   303    0        0 lo
192.168.1.134   127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   303    0        0 lo
```

route -n (after VPN):

```
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tap0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
46...........   192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.2     127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   302    0        0 lo
192.168.1.134   127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   302    0        0 lo
192.168.1.135   127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   302    0        0 lo
```

My router is at 192.168.1.1.

I can connect to VPN but I have no internet access.The field

> Use only for resources on this connection

is not checked.
If I check it,then I can have internet access but as I can see traceroute is the same before and after VPN.Also,the IP doesn't change.

/etc/config/openvpn

```
config 'openvpn' 'lan'
   option 'enable' '1'
   option 'port' '1194'
   option 'proto' 'udp'
   option 'dev' 'tap0'
   option 'ca' '/etc/openvpn/ca.crt'
   option 'cert' '/etc/openvpn/server.crt'
   option 'key' '/etc/openvpn/server.key'
   option 'dh' '/etc/openvpn/dh1024.pem'
   option 'ifconfig_pool_persist' '/tmp/ipp.txt'
   option 'keepalive' '10 120'
   option 'comp_lzo' '1'
   option 'persist_key' '1'
   list 'push' 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1'
   option 'server_bridge' '10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.10'
```

/etc/config/firewall

```
config  'rule'
    option 'target' 'ACCEPT'
    option 'dest_port' '1194'
    option 'src' 'wan'
    option 'proto' 'tcpudp'
    option 'family' 'ipv4'
```

Comment: If you initially HAVE internet access, and then it goes away, it suggests something like dhcpcd is running which changes your network configuration after a period of time. Is there anything like that happening?

Comment: @Xyon:I am using a hostname from noip and I am using /etc/config/dhcp